# My Goodman furnace shuts off

Tags: furnace

My Goodman furnace with purchase in 2015 and every year I have to clean the sensor this year it shuts off and I go in the basement and flip the switch and it comes back on it does it every 3 or 4 days

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info and clarity before we can help you. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.